# Get the app script project created in spreadsheet to eclipse

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have installed Google plugin for eclipse yesterday and when I start importing app script projects it shows projects available only in myDrive.

I have created few app projects in google spreadsheets.

How can I retrieve those projects created in the spreadsheet to eclipse?

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

If you were to read the plugin docs you'll see that it's not supported.